# Read XML file Locally from Javascript in Chrome OR IE ; which should be compatible for Android Mobile Also

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, bootstrap-modal

I need to read an XML file locally from HTML page , and display data accordingly on web page without any webServer.

I need to do it using Javascript Or Jquery Or Ajax

Comment: I need to do it using Javascript Or Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is used to display data i.e. it is an User interface part. XML is used to stored data. 
For fetching data from XML and to display in HTML part you will have to use some programming  languages, like JavaScript, Angular, Java, C#, Php, etc.

Comment: I need to do via JavaScript . But the reading should not be done via any Server Engine (like Visual Studio localhost etc... ) . It should be via file browsing only.